# Offline PWA as a ChromOS Kiosk Application

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, google-chrome-os

How can I adapt my Chrome packaged apps for ChromeOS Kiosks following their depreciation? I've begun experimenting with PWAs as an alternative, and while they work online and offline on various devices, when installed as a Kiosk app, they only function online, offline functionality is required. Any insights on resolving this issue?

Service Worker

```
const CACHE_NAME = 'cache-v1';
const urlsToCache = [
  '/', // Include the root URL to handle HTML updates
  'https://server'
  'https://server/index.html',
  'https://server/Main.css',
  'https://server/Main.js',
  // Add more resources as needed
];

self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then((cache) => cache.addAll(urlsToCache))
      .then(() => self.skipWaiting())
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', (event) => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then((cacheNames) => {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map((cacheName) => {
          if (cacheName !== CACHE_NAME) {
            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then((cachedResponse) => {
        if (cachedResponse) {
          return cachedResponse;
        }

        return fetch(event.request)
          .then((response) => {
            // Check if we received a valid response
            if (!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
              return response;
            }

            const responseToCache = response.clone();
            caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
              .then((cache) => cache.put(event.request, responseToCache));

            return response;
          });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        return caches.match(event.request);
      })
  );
});
```

Manifest

```
{
  "name": "Kiosk App 0_0_3_1",
  "description": "DESCRIPTION",
  "version": "0.0.3.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "start_url": "./Main.html",
  "display": "standalone",
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "service-worker.js"
  },
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "./icon48.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "./icon128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png"
    },
    {
      "src": "./icon144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ],
  "screenshots": [
    {
      "src": "/logo.gif",
      "sizes": "600x600",
      "type": "image/gif",
      "form_factor": "wide",
      "label": "Application"
    },
    {
      "src": "/logo.gif",
      "sizes": "600x600",
      "type": "image/gif",
      "label": "Application"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "contentSettings",
    "webRequest",
    {
      "host_permissions": [
        "*://*.google.com/*",
        "*://www.googleapis.com/*",
        "*://*.googleusercontent.com/*",
      ]
    }
  ],
  "kiosk_enabled": true,
  "kiosk": {
    "required_platform_version": "13982",
    "always_update": true
  }
}
```

Comment: _"How can I adapt my Chrome packaged apps for Kiosks following their depreciation?"_ WIndow management, full screen.

Comment: @guest271314 I dont really understand how window management relates to my issue?

Comment: If I understand your question you want to manipulate and control the `window` of the application? You can use an Isolated Web App and `"display_override"` in the manifest to control window behaviour. Technically you can also use `"display"` property, too, to create your kiosk mode, see https://github.com/michaelwasserman/iwa-windowing-example.

Comment: No the display isnt a problem, the PWA when installed to my chromeOS kiosks (through google admin) is fullscreen and working, It just doesnt work offline.

Comment: I don't have any experience with ChromeOS. That's the closest to what you are doing that I can think of.